# Crud-repository are not getting scan after upgrading spring boot from 1.5.13.RELEASE to 2.2.4.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, autowired

Description:

required a bean of type `com.abc.repositories.XYZCrudReposotry` that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)`

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type `com.abc.repositories.XYZCrudReposotry` in your configuration.

In earlier Spring boot version i was able to use autowired for repository interfaces but after upgrade when i start the application it gives above error.

Comment: add `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.abc.repositories)` to your configuration.

Comment: make sure you annotated your repository interface with `@Repository`

Comment: @ŁukaszOlszewski after adding ```@EnableJpaRepositories``` it worked, did not specify the ```com.abc.repositories```.

Now getting ```com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The "variant" data type is not supported.```

Comment: I happy that repositories work, you can give me up-vote :) In case of  "variant" issue, maybe try to update  `mssql-jdbc` to the newest version.